# mdadm automount

Tags: 13.10, raid, automount, lvm, mdadm

I have a system running ubuntu 13.10, booting from a 50GB SSD.  Attached to the motherboard are also three 2TB disks.  configured into a 4TB RAID array.  After ubuntu boots, I can mount the RAD volume successfully with:

```
sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /data
```

after which I can access the files in the array in /data

I am uncertain as to how to get this mounting process to happen automatically during booting, however.  I tried the "Disks" GUI program without success.

I have seen posts mentioning how I should edit `fstab` and/or `mdadm.conf`, but I have not seen any really clear instructions regarding exactly what lines to add to either of these files.

I don't remember how the three 2TB disks were setup, formatted, etc. to become a RAID volume.  I vaguely recall that both mdadm and Logical Volume Manager were used, but it was a long time ago.  So when I see instructions requiring me to know how the disks are formatted, I am stuck.  All I really know for sure is that the above command works.

Any pointers to really clear, noob-level instructions for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your array is probably reassembled either automatically (by looking at the metadata on the disks) or in the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file.

LVM, which lives on top of that, is initialized automatically as well.

To just have a certain volume mounted at boot is simply adding an entry in `/etc/fstab`, e.g.:

```
/dev/vgname/lvname      /path/to/mountpoint     ext4    defaults         0      2
```

Read the fstab(5) manpage for more information on the exact settings (`man fstab`). This example is of an `ext4` filesystem with all default settings for a file system without dependencies for booting up (nothing related to `/usr`, `/lib` or something like that).